# When show UIAlertView in iOS 6.1.2, the memory leaks happen

Tags: ios6, uialertview, memory-leaks

**strong text**When show UIAlertView in iOS 6.1.2, app will get memory leaks like following:

```
__NSDictionaryM 1   0x1e5c6000  32 Bytes    TextInput   __92-[TIResourcePathManager     fetchAssetsWithNames:forInputModes:updatingDictionary:continuation:]_block_invoke_0
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x1e5d5320  16 Bytes    TextInput   __92-[TIResourcePathManager   fetchAssetsWithNames:forInputModes:updatingDictionary:continuation:]_block_invoke_0
```

Codes like following,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.row == 1 && indexPath.section == 1) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert autorelease];
}
```

So why?

**PS. Maybe I forget to say that this UIAlertView may show many times one by one, so sometimes first time show the UIAlertView will okay,but when I try several times, the memory leaks will happen.**

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

`[alert autorelease];`

with:

`[alert release];`

Comment: With release or autorelease, the memory leaks will happen always.

Comment: define `UIAlertView` as `ClassLevel` and `alloc init` in `ViewDidLod` and set text in `didSelectRow` method.

Comment: And why would that fix a memory leak?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I forget to say that the UIAlertView will show many times, so the method you said doesn't fix it.